# Magento How to Export/Import all products from all store in a single fetch/dump?

Tags: magento-1.9, import, export, importexport, ce-1.9.2.1

How can be able to import products CSV to all store from admin back end in a single shot. Also Export all products of all store in a single shot in admin back end.

If any extension available or if not means how we can achieve this using coding?

Consider I have three stores in a sites like this

1. www.store1.example.com
2. www.store2.example.com
3. www.store3.example.com

So will admin user able to export all products in this three domain in to single csv also import it to at a time in all domain?

Comment: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-exportimport-data-in-csv-files.html have a look there

Comment: @LukeRodgers but it is for only store scope but I required for all website's store's products in a single csv. I will update the question.